# Passing Data Tables Into Functions

Tags: vb.net, parameter-passing

When you try to pass a datatable into another function, what do  you type in when you call for it?

```
Private Function getC()
    ....
End Function

Private Sub reClick(ByVal dt2 As DataTable)
    ....
End Sub

   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    getC()
    reClick(dt2:=getC())
End Sub
```

`getCoordinates()` returns a datatable, and I want to pass that same datatable into `reClick()`. However, when I go to pass in the `dt2` ,it comes up as `dt2:=`. I don't know what this means, or what expression I'm supposed to set it equal too.

Comment: Is this perhaps part of an excel macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking this. All you want is:

```
reClick(getC())
```

the `dt2:=` syntax is used for named parameters, if you have optional parameters to the function that you're trying to omit. Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you, yes I was definitely making it more difficult than I needed to!